# How do i programatically find the exact place of a control on a form/page

Tags: ms-access, vba

```vb
Function RequiredFieldsMissing(frm As Form) As Boolean
Dim foundEmpty As Boolean
Dim txt As TextBox
Dim cmb As ComboBox
Dim pge As Page
Dim Ctrl As Control
Dim formName As String`

    foundEmpty = False
    formName = frm.Name
    For Each Ctrl In frm.Controls
        If Len(Ctrl.Name) > 6 Then
            If left(Ctrl.Name, 3) = "txt" And right(Ctrl.Name, 3) = "Req" Then
                Set txt = Ctrl
                If IsNull(txt.value) Then
                    foundEmpty = True
                    txt.BackColor = constLngRed
                    'Form_Clients.TabClientData.Pages(1).SetFocus
                    txt.SetFocus
                Else
                    If Len(txt.value) = 0 Then
                        foundEmpty = True
                        txt.BackColor = constLngRed
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            If left(Ctrl.Name, 3) = "cmb" And right(Ctrl.Name, 3) = "Req" Then
                Set cmb = Ctrl
                If IsNull(cmb.value) Then
                    foundEmpty = True
                    cmb.BackColor = constLngRed
                Else
                    If Len(cmb.value) = 0 Then
                        foundEmpty = True
                        cmb.BackColor = constLngRed
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next Ctrl

    RequiredFieldsMissing = foundEmpty
End Function
```

The function above will colour and highlight the control that does not have data...the problem is that i need to set focus to the control but sometimes the control resides on a sub form and on a page.
If i do txt.setfocus, then it will set focus to that control but not move to the residing page. Also the only variable I pass is the form.

My question is as follows...

How can i set focus to that control that resides on a page when i only pass the form name?

Comment: if 10 controls have no data, you can't put the focus on all 10 of them. Finish your loop with coloring it and then just before exit set focus to the first or last control.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call SetFocus twice: once to set the focus to the subform (on the main form), and once to set the focus to the control on the subform.

Comment: Hi Krish, I managed to resolve this myself but I cannot answer my posts yet because of some restrictions, I am not sure how to get these restrictions lifted. I would like to post my code that I wrote! so that it may help others if they have a similar situation, Basically i passed the tab control and form to another function and if the color of that control was red then I alliterated the page number and set focus to page and the control that needed data.